# Images in gridview showing in emulator but not in device

Tags: android

I have an image gridView and I am using the images from the url.

It is working properly in the emulator but the images do not show in the device. There is no error in the logcat. The following is the code which I have tried.

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener,
        OnClickListener {

    TabHost tabHost;
    View vi;
    StaggeredAdapter adapter;
    TextView tv;
    public String urls[] = {

    "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8462/8005636463_0cb4ea6be2.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7232/6913504132_a0fce67a0e_c.jpg",
            "http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4133/5096108108_df62764fcc_b.jpg",
            "http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4074/4789681330_2e30dfcacb_b.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8208/8219397252_a04e2184b2.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8483/8218023445_02037c8fda.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8335/8144074340_38a4c622ab.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8060/8173387478_a117990661.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8056/8144042175_28c3564cd3.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8183/8088373701_c9281fc202.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8185/8081514424_270630b7a5.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8462/8005636463_0cb4ea6be2.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8306/7987149886_6535bf7055.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8444/7947923460_18ffdce3a5.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8182/7941954368_3c88ba4a28.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8304/7832284992_244762c43d.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8163/7709112696_3c7149a90a.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7127/7675112872_e92b1dbe35.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7111/7429651528_a23ebb0b8c.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8288/7525381378_aa2917fa0e.jpg",
            "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5336/7384863678_5ef87814fe.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7102/7179457127_36e1cbaab7.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7086/7238812536_1334d78c05.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7243/7193236466_33a37765a4.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7251/7059629417_e0e96a4c46.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7084/6885444694_6272874cfc.jpg" };

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public StaggeredGridView PremiumgridView;
    public StaggeredGridView FeaturedgridView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        Button iv = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnMoreDialog);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu homepopup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), v);

                MenuInflater inflater = homepopup.getMenuInflater();

                inflater.inflate(R.menu.moredialog, homepopup.getMenu());

                homepopup.show();

            }
        });

        PremiumgridView = (StaggeredGridView) vi.findViewById(R.id.premiumstaggeredGridView);

        new Dialogs().execute(urls);

        return vi;
    }

    private class Dialogs extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String[]> {
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... params) {
            return params[0];
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            Log.d("url", result[0]);
            String new_string = result[0].replaceAll("http://", "www.");
            Log.d("urls", new_string);

            // Premium Dialog

            int premiummargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin);
            PremiumgridView.setItemMargin(premiummargin);
            PremiumgridView.setPadding(premiummargin, 0, premiummargin, 0);

            StaggeredAdapter premiumadapter = new StaggeredAdapter(vi.getContext(),
                    R.id.photoimageview, result, R.layout.row_staggered_demo);

            PremiumgridView.setAdapter(premiumadapter);
            premiumadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // nothing to do
        }
    }
}
```

My Adapter class

StaggeredAdapter.java

```
public class StaggeredAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements
        OnClickListener {

    private ImageLoader mLoader;
    private int _row;
    private Context _context;

    public StaggeredAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects, int row) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        _context = context;
        mLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        _row = row;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.row_staggered_demo, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ScaleImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.photoimageview);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        mLoader.DisplayImage(getItem(position), holder.imageView);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ScaleImageView imageView;
        LinearLayout view;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(_context, "buffering......... please wait...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions pls?

Thanks,

Comment: Does your device connected to the internet? have you try disconnect and connect again the device to the internet?

Comment: What is ImageLoader? Have You tried to put logs in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your free space on the device there must be less. So that it cannot retrieve the images from sdcard. And your device must me connected with the working internet.

otherwise you must have given this in menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

no other issue.

Comment: I have tried on two three devices but the image is not displayed on any of them. Why so?

Comment: great what was the problem? All device didn't have memory in SDcard

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked on both tablet and phone. Will the same work in gingerbread? I have not tried on it.